# Pending intents extra's are lost

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Hi i am trying to create a pending intent that has a enum contained in its intent extras that launches a broadcast reciever via alarm manager but my code crashes on the broadcast receiver when i tries to get the enum saying it is null?

Here is my code below

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val intent = Intent(context, ClearDataReceiver::class.java)
        intent.action = "clear data"
        intent.putExtra(ClearDataReceiver.DATA_TYPE_EXTRA, DataType.CUSTOMER_DETAILS )
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, 60 * 1, pendingIntent)
```

the broadcast reciever

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent)

    var bundle = intent!!.extras

    val dataType = bundle.getSerializable(DATA_TYPE_EXTRA) as DataType
    when(dataType){
        DataType.BALANCE -> storage.clearCurrentBalance()
        DataType.CARD_NUMBER -> storage.clearardNumber()
        DataType.CUSTOMER_DETAILS -> storage.clearUserDetails()

    }
}
```

Comment: yes thats a typo when i was copying the code here. ammending it now

Comment: Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` for the last parameter of `getBroadcast()`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Still no extra's being included. even the set action value is lost!?!!?

Answer (score 5):

You can no longer put custom objects into the "extras" `Bundle` in an `Intent` that you pass to `AlarmManager`. The Android framework tries to deserialize these custom objects and fails which is why you won't see the custom objects in the `Bundle` when the alarm triggers.

Here are 2 alternatives:

1. Put the data in an SQLite database or a file and not in the "extras". You can put an ID or some other unique value into the "extras" to help you identify the data, but it must be a primitive (like `int`) or a `String`.
2. Serialize (or convert) the custom object into a `byte` array or a `String` and put that in the "extras". Android can then deserialize this without problems. When your alarm triggers, you can convert the `byte` array or `String` back into your custom object.

Comment: I'll give that a go. But the object in question was a enum

Comment: Can you please add the link to document pointing out this feature. I couldn't  find any.

Comment: Here's 2: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/alarms-pendingintents-cannot-include-custom-parcelable-class-instances-on-android-n-93a64aeedb33

Comment: You can easily convert `enum` to `String` or `int`.

Comment: I also noticed that you have set a repeating alarm with a repeat frequency of 60ms. This won't work. You cannot reliably set a repeating alarm with frequencies under 2 minutes. `AlarmManager` isn't designed for that. If you need a trigger every 60ms, you need to post a message or `Runnable` to a `Handler`.

Comment: The intent extra is still null even when i pass just a string on it. the intent bundle has no extras at all!

Comment: Just for fun, try using "clear_data" as your ACTION instead of "clear data". I've never seen anyone use a space character in an ACTION before and maybe that's causing some issue (although I doubt it). I'm running out of ideas, this sounds very strange.

Comment: yea i tried that no joy. if i direcntly start the broadcast reciever using context.startbroadcas with  the exact same intent. it works! somethings going wrong the pending intent or the alarm manager

Comment: In any case, you should use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` as the 4th parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try for

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

Comment: No joy, the extras are all empty! this weird, even teh action is empty!