# BroadcastReceiver Intent delivered without extras

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

My `BroadcastReceiver` is not receiving the `Intent` extras when it gets delivered.

Here's how I create the `PendingIntent`

```
private fun getPendingIntent(type: ReminderType, date: DateTime): PendingIntent {
    val context = App.appContext
    val intent = Intent(context, TimeBasedRemindersBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(ARG_REMINDER_TYPE, type)
    intent.putExtra(ARG_DATE_TIME, date)
    val intentFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    } else {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }
    val requestCode = date.dayOfWeek * 100 + type.ordinal
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        requestCode,
        intent,
        intentFlags
    )
}
```

As you can see, the extras are clearly appended as soon as the Intent is initialised. When the `BroadcastReceiver` gets fired, the `intent.extras` is empty.

After researching this, I can only assume this has something to do with Android 12 and mutability intent flags. All of the older answers to this question seem to fix it by just adding the `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag.

I have also tried the same code running with `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` but the result is the same.

Not sure if it matters, but I am using `AlarmManager` to deliver the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073675/pending-intents-extras-are-lost

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel Unfortunately not. Putting a String instead of a Serializable in the extras was one of the first things I tried when troubleshooting.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel Your comment actually ended up helping me come to a solution. When I was initially troubleshooting with primitive type, my extras were still not coming through. Only after removing the problematic line did it start to work. Seems like only one failed serialization is enough for the Intent to lose all extras, not just the one that failed. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @ShlomiKatriel commented above and pointed me to a similar question, I have come to a solution.

The reason this happens is because `Intent` does not know how to serialize and deserialize every type of object.

In my case, the problematic line was:

```
intent.putExtra(ARG_REMINDER_TYPE, type)
```

Because the type that I was trying to pass as extra was actually an `enum`. What makes this very confusing is that if a single serialization fails, it loses ALL of the data, not just the one that failed. That's why my `ARG_DATE_TIME` was being lost as well.

After I've replaced the enum extra with a primitive type, it started to work as expected and I could access my other extras as well.